# How to bind parameters in prepared SQL statements?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I want to query my MySQL database using prepared statements. The query should look like:

```
SELECT name, idname FROM names WHERE origin='english' AND name like('%a%')"
```

This one works great:

```
$origin = "english";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, idname FROM names WHERE origin=? AND name like('%a%')"))
$stmt->bind_param("s", $origin);
```

But this doesn't work at all (even without an error):

```
$origin = "english";
$letter = "a";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, idname FROM names WHERE origin=? AND name like(%?%)")) 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $origin, $letter);
```

Please mind the last term `like`. I don't know how to bind the second parameter `letter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value to `LIKE` predicate using the `CONCAT` statement.

#### Corrected version:

```
$origin = "english";
$letter = "a";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, idname FROM names WHERE origin=? 
AND name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')")) 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $origin, $letter);
```

Comment: I get this error `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`.